# PostScript's readstring: Is there a more efficient way to parse lines?

Tags: algorithm, performance, postscript

A very old PostScript code of mine that parses input lines goes like this:

```
/buff 1 string def      % check for line wrap every character
/EOLchar (\n) def       % line feed

{ %loop
        currentfile buff readstring exch
        dup EOLchar eq
    { %ifelse
        %...
    }
    { %else
        %...
    } ifelse
    not { %if readstring found EOF
        exit    % end of file
    } if
} loop
```

Is there a more efficient way to read whole lines for further processing?

I want to embed data to plot into the file, and every line would describe a line segment.
Each line consists of multiple numeric fields, separated by a TAB character (so I'll split the lines into fields, and convert the field strings to `int` or `real` for ease of processing).

Of course I could convert the plot data externally (e.g. to a PostSript array), but my idea was to add some fixed magic PostScript header to each data file, and it's going to render the data...

Comment: Probably better to ask on SO honestly since there is no graphics problem. Although you dont define why youd parse i  first  place. Best would be to pass a list.

Comment: In the meantime I tried this approach: Read everything at once in a large buffer (assuming the file is not very big), then use `search` to build an array of lines.

Comment: You can use readline instead of readstring, assuming your lines are terminated with \n, \r or both. That saves you having to read byte-by-byte, and checking each character for an EOL, which will be faster. Two possible problems depending on the '...' content; firstly the EOL is not stored in the string, secondly if the string isn't loing enough to read the entire line from the file then you get a rangecheck error. Strings are limited to 64Kb in Adobe PostScript interpreters so you should think of that as teh maximum string you can define..

Comment: There's also the SubFileDecode filter, which *might* be appropraite, but it depends what you are doing with the data after you read it.

Answer (score 1):

How about something more like this? 
`readline` handles lines for you (up to the string capacity defined by the interpreter). `token` handles skipping whitespace and converting numbers into real or integer as appropriate.

Note also that the boolean result from the file reading operators can be used to exit from the loop early, which seems efficient.

```
/buf 65535 string def
/f currentfile def
{
  f buf readline not {exit} if
  { token {exch}{exit} ifelse } loop
  {lineto} stopped {moveto} if
} loop
100 200
300 400
500 600
```